# Selenium IDE - WaitFors that are passing when they shouldnt

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a small test case which automates filling in a form.

This form is an iFrame from sagepay (I'm aware this could cause some issues)

This form doesn't have a name, class or id (Meaning to latch onto it is problematic)

Code below

```
<!--Sagepay-->
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=img.sageimg</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertElementPresent</td>
    <td>//div[@id='holrightcontainer']/div[2]/div/div/img[2]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=proceedButton</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=#formCardDetails &gt; div &gt; span.errortext</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=div.details-inner</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=iframe</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>name=cardnumber</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>name=cardpostcode</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=cardnumber</td>
    <td>${cardNumber}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=cardfirstnames</td>
    <td>${cardFirstName}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=cardsurname</td>
    <td>${cardSurname}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertElementPresent</td>
    <td>name=startmonth</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>name=startmonth</td>
    <td>${cardMonthStart}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>name=startyear</td>
    <td>${cardYearStart}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>name=expirymonth</td>
    <td>${cardMonthEnd}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>name=expiryyear</td>
    <td>${cardYearEnd}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=securitycode</td>
    <td>${cardSecurityCode}</td>
</tr>
```

Now comes the tricky bit... It sometimes skips some of the form type fields, and fails on any one from 3-6 periodically.

I run my tests at Speed 0, but this shouldn't be a problem.

The WaitFor's beforehand all pass to let me know the elements are there, but then going forward is the issue!

Any advice? I've tried looking online for other tips, not found anything. Only other option I can think of is connecting to the sagepay site directly using the url, but I shouldn't need to.

Comment: The elements exist in the DOM, but maybe they are hidden or not active yet. My guess is that selenium is not running on the fields you want them to and there is another form on the page it's hooking on to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same issue with a number of search forms on the site I test. What I've found works for me (YMMV), is to have installed the plugin Implicit Wait (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-implicit-wait/), and in some troublesome cases, have a WaitForElementPresent followed immediately by a VerifyElementPresent on the same locator.

When I first started using Selenium IDE, I used "pauses" quite a bit, but found I was able to eliminate those and improve the execution speed and reliability of the tests.

Klendathu

Comment: Pauses should be avoided whenever possible, replace with Wait For.

Answer (score 0):

I found one of the main issues, and a way around it (Although the Implicit Wait plugin I did research and found to be useful)

As the main issue I had was regarding waiting for error pop-ups. And the problem was concerning a click command which then reloaded the page, I found that a better wait was the following.

```
waitForText | locator | regex:.+?
```

This allowed me to wait until the error was populated, as both WaitForVisible and WaitForElementPresent gave me faux passes